# Jupyter Lab and Folium map: adding MarkerCluster result blank screen

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, folium

On IBM Watson Studion notebook, the result is ok.
In Anaconda Jupyter Lab, when I create a folium map with CircleMarker labels, it works, but after adding MarkerCluster to it, the result is a blank screen.
Any tips?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import folium
from folium import plugins
from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster
    
# DataFrames
link_M = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M"
df_Toronto = pd.read_html(link_M)[0]
df_Toronto = df_Toronto[df_Toronto['Borough']!='Not assigned']
df_Toronto['Neighborhood'].replace('Not assigned', df_Toronto['Borough'], inplace=True)

my_dict = {'Neighborhood': 'North York (York Heights / Victoria Village / Parkway East)',  'Neighborhood_Latitude': 43.7545, 'Neighborhood_Longitude': -79.33, 'Venue': 'Tim Hortons','Venue_Latitude': 43.760668270302276, 'Venue_Longitude': -79.32636763515987,'Venue_Category': 'CafÃ©'}, {'Unnamed: 0': 1, 'Neighborhood': 'North York (York Heights / Victoria Village / Parkway East)',
  'Neighborhood_Latitude': 43.7545, 'Neighborhood_Longitude': -79.33, 'Venue': 'La Notre', 'Venue_Latitude': 43.76070416249771, 'Venue_Longitude': -79.32539551954271, 'Venue_Category': 'Coffee Shop'}, {'Unnamed: 0': 2, 'Neighborhood': 'North York (Sweeney Park / Wigmore Park)', 'Neighborhood_Latitude': 43.7276,'Neighborhood_Longitude': -79.3148,'Venue': 'Tim Hortons','Venue_Latitude': 43.725516631714754, 'Venue_Longitude': -79.31310251366091,'Venue_Category': 'Coffee Shop'},{'Unnamed: 0': 3,'Neighborhood': 'North York (Sweeney Park / Wigmore Park)', 'Neighborhood_Latitude': 43.7276, 'Neighborhood_Longitude': -79.3148,'Venue': 'Tim Hortons', 'Venue_Latitude': 43.7270816, 'Venue_Longitude': -79.327143, 'Venue_Category': 'Coffee Shop'},{'Unnamed: 0': 4,'Neighborhood': 'Downtown Toronto (Regent Park / Port of Toronto)', 'Neighborhood_Latitude': 43.6555,  'Neighborhood_Longitude': -79.3626, 'Venue': 'Tandem Coffee', 'Venue_Latitude': 43.65355870959944, 'Venue_Longitude': -79.36180945913512, 'Venue_Category': 'Coffee Shop'}
toronto_coffee.from_dict(my_dict)

map_toronto = folium.Map(location=[lat_tor, long_tor], zoom_start=11)
    
for lat, lng, label in zip(df_Toronto['latitude'], df_Toronto['longitude'], df_Toronto['Neighborhood']):
        label = folium.Popup(label, parse_html=True)
        folium.CircleMarker(
            [lat, lng],
            radius=4,
            popup=label,
            color='blue',
            fill=True,
            fill_color='#3186cc',
            fill_opacity=0.7,
            parse_html=False).add_to(map_toronto)  
    
# instantiate a mark cluster object for the incidents in the dataframe
incidents = folium.plugins.MarkerCluster().add_to(map_toronto)
    
# loop through the dataframe and add each data point to the mark cluster
for lat, lng, label, in zip(toronto_coffee['Venue_Latitude'], toronto_coffee['Venue_Longitude'], toronto_coffee['Venue']):
            folium.Marker(
            location=[lat, lng],
            icon=None,
            popup=label,
            ).add_to(incidents)
        
map_toronto
```

Comment: Please, provide `df_Toronto` and `toronto_coffee` in a usable format. Thanks.

Comment: Done, sorry about that.

Comment: It seems you provided incomplete code.

Comment: You can check the complete notebook here:
https://github.com/danilodn/Coursera_Capstone2/blob/master/Capstone2.ipynb